# Exporting generated geometry from geometry nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I'm new to the Geometry Editor side of Blender. I was referencing the following thread:

[How to use random spheres inside a cube with Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262436/how-to-use-random-spheres-inside-a-cube-with-geometry-nodes)

Which overall is great but I want to export the resulting spheres as STLs. When I do that, (having 'Selection Only' applied) there is no geometry detected when uploading to other CAD software. Am I missing something? Thank you!

Comment: Hi David. Try adding Realize Instances node before the Group Output. This will convert all instances into meshes.